# How can I return a "CGI Escaped String" in PHP?

Tags: php, json

the [TMDb documentation](http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#search) says that I have to put a CGI escaped string in order to do a JSON request. I use PHP and i have the following string.

```
$string = "Movie name";
$search = $tmdb->searchMovie($string);
```

$string have to be "CGI escaped" to put it in the JSON API request.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it means this

```
urlencode(string);
```

so in your case:

```
$search = $tmdb->searchMovie(urlencode($string));
```

Comment: I knew this function but I didn't know that is called "CGI escape" too. However, it works like charm. Thank you :)